# rbx animator: when i use this addon i am getting this error

Tags: python, scripting

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kex30\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\V5aBemWL.py", line 439, in execute
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=self.properties.filepath, use_split_groups=True)
  File "D:\games\steamapps\common\Blender\4.0\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 109, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), kw)
AttributeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.import_scene.obj" error, could not be found
```

Comment: That's a third-party addon so it's quite possible that it hasn't been updated to work with the Blender version 4 APIs. Check on the addon's web page to see if it's been updated.